# Inserting in a table after crossing the allocated tablespace space

Tags: oracle, database-design

What will happen when I try to insert so many number of rows beyond the allocated tablespace size.
Say in Oracle DB, the initial tablespace size is set to 500MB and when it reached the limit and we try to create more records into it, should it fail or it will acquire more space from the hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will throw an error and rollback the query.

> ORA-01653: unable to extend table by in tablespace

Comment: Unless autoextend is enabled to at least one of the datafiles in tablespace and there is enough space on the disk.

Comment: That is true but the OP did not mention this. With autoextend it continues until it reaches the max_size of the autoextend or the diskspace before the error is thrown.